# turning a windows service into a web app core service?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core

I have a windows service which allows incoming and outgoing connections to a UDP port that is using Lidgren UDP networking library.

I've been really wanting to change this to use .net core for some of the obvious cross platform benefits and other benefits like deployment and scaling within Microsoft's Azure Cloud.

It seems the only easy way to do this is to use the Web Core app which is not really what im doing(Its not handling http requests).

I've done tons of googling to figure out how to handle this situation and the only thing i have found is a library called WindowsService for .net core but that just allows me to convert a 462 app to .net core and continue using windows service which is not ideal.

TLDR; Can anyone shed some light on how i can convert a windows service which is handling UDP Traffic into a deployable application for azure?

Comment: Can you convert it to a docker container? Then  you can host it in azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-service/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been really wanting to change this to use .net core for some of the obvious cross platform benefits

Before changing to .NET Core, you need to confirm whether all the dependent assemblies support .NET Core.

> Can anyone shed some light on how i can convert a windows service which is handling UDP Traffic into a deployable application for azure?

There are multi services which support windows service on Azure. Based on your description, you could choose Azure VM scale sets, Azure Cloud Service and Azure Service Fabric to host your windows service. All of these services could listen on an UDP port to get/send a message from/to client.

You don't need to modify your code if you choose Azure VM scale sets. You can also package your Windows Service to a executable file and deploy it to Cloud Service or Service Fabric. You could also check following document to check the [differences between Cloud Service and Service Fabric](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-differences.md).